# Determining Y value when drawing tiles

Tags: javascript

I have a canvas, let's say it's 1000 pixels wide

I have a constant size of each tile I want to draw, let's say it's 100px wide and 100 pixels tall

With this I can determine how many tiles per row I can have

I have the number of tiles required, it's an array of objects let's say with a length of 10 (e.g. 10 objects)

I can determine how many rows I will need to display all these tiles

But for the life of me I can't figure out what Y value to assign

Let's say it's

myArray.map( (item, index) => {
x: 0,
y: ?
});

Comment: Whis are "X value" and "Y value" in your case? Are those coordinates of tiles where something else will draw them?

Comment: Instead of "let's say, let's say" how about you post a [mcve]?

Comment: Math.floor(els/(elwidth/canvaswidth))+1 // <- some basic logic

Comment: @Jonasw els being?

Comment: @yeputons yes they'll be draw somewhere else.

Comment: @joshunderwood then your question has little to do with implementation, as I see it: you have to decide yourself what Y coordinate should your tiles have depending on the task you have.